# How to return to home page upon clicking Cancel in a wizard in Odoo 12?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-12

I am using Odoo 12's enterprise version code for customization and I need to redirect to the homepage (web#home) from a wizard upon clicking the cancel button. I searched a lot to find the menu_id or action which calls the homepage to return it from a python method, but I could not find it. Is there any way to do this or not? Below is my code in python file where I want to return the action or menu of the homepage:

```
def action_cancel(self):
        return {
            'name': _("Main Menu"),
            'type': 'ir.actions.client',
            'tag': 'reload',
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use `ir.actions.act_url`

Eg:

```
def action_cancel(self):
   return {
      'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
      'target': 'self',
      'url': '/home'
   }
```

Comment: It just a little problem, after clicking on the button a new window opens and redirects to wanted URL. What should I do to open in in the current window?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this will only work if the website module is not installed.

You are looking for the 'home' client action. Change the tag to home:

```
'tag': 'home',
```

It is defined in /addons/web/static/src/js/core/misc.js

```
/**
 * Client action to go back home.
 */
function Home (parent, action) {
    var url = '/' + (window.location.search || '');
    redirect(url, action && action.params && action.params.wait);
}
core.action_registry.add("home", Home);
```

So ... apparently the client action can be as simple as a function!

Comment: Actually above tag is for the home of website and not for where I need to redirect there. I need to redirect to this URL: /web#home. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I forgot when you install the website module it won't work!

Comment: OK, I have just fix my problem with above solution. But i could not find any tag for this purpose.

Comment: You can make your own. just replace the '/' with '/web' and give it a new tag name.